# Hibernate - Map the same column to two diferent variables

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to map the same column to two diferent variables, like the following code:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="Class", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private ObjectClass classObject;

@Column(name="Class")
private int classID;
```

But when i try to get the classObject i get a null and the classID is with the right value. For some reason the classObject is not getting fetched....

Can you guys help???

Comment: This looks not right. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: in the context i only have the the id,so i insert the id, but i want to get both the id and the object. i want to use the id to insert in the db, but use the annotation to retrieve the object

Comment: As from what I understand: Try it this way -> Before you insert anything, search for the object with this id (Which obviously needs to exist if you want to build a relationship.) Now insert the found object directly.
It might be helpful if you work a few tutorials. e.g. https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/